# Merging observable collection with collection of observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an API call that returns an observable collection of objects. For each object in that observable collection I need to do another API call to get an observable value.

What is the correct way to merge an observable collection with a collection of observables so that the result is an observable collection where we get rid of  extra data ?

**I.E: (1:n) -> 1**

**Concretely**:

```
// getMarkets API response:
[   {
    "data": [
      {
        "mkt_name": "X",
        ...
      },
      {...}, {...}, {...} 
      //there is a lot of these, cardinality changes over time
    ]}
]
//getTicker(market=X) API response:
[   {
    "data": [
      {
        "last_trade": "651.4000000000",
        ...
      }
      //there is only one of this, "last_trade" value changes a lot more over time
    ],
    "notifications": []
    }
]
```

and I need

```
//getMarketsWithTickers Service response (! Also Observable !)
[ 
  {"market" : "X", "last_trade" : "651.4000000000" },  
  {...}, 
  {...}, 
  {...}
]
```

How do I implement `getMarketWithTickers` using `getMarkets`/`getTicker` observables ?

NOTE: I am new to this whole RxJS thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete runnable example showing what you can do;

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// what you already have (simulated):
interface Market {
  name: string;
}

interface Trade {
  lastTrade: string;
}

function getMarkets() {
  return Observable.of({data: [{name: 'm1'}, {name: 'm2'}, {name: 'm3'}] as Array<Market>})
}

function getTicker(marketName: string) {
  return Observable.of({data: {lastTrade: marketName.substring(1)}});
}

// what you can do:
getMarkets()
  .map(obj => obj.data.map(market => market.name)) //1
  .switchMap(marketNames =>
    Observable.forkJoin( // 4
      ...marketNames.map(market => getTicker(market) // 2
      .map(ticker => +ticker.data.lastTrade))) // 3
  )
  .subscribe(trades => console.log(trades.join(', ')));
```

Short explanation (read the documentation for more details):

1. you transform your observable of collection of markets into an observable of market names using the map operator
2. When you receive the array of market names, you create for each of them, an observable of Ticker.
3. each observable of Ticker is transformed into an observable of lastTrade, one again using the map operator
4. you use the forkJoin method to create an observable emitting an array containing the (last) emitted event of each of the observables of lastTrade

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around the syntax in the `forkJoin` method : are the `...` in front there to signal that it is actually a collection of observables ? 
 
- Anyway I now have other issues along the lines of `HTTP 429: too many requests`. Do you have any insight onto how to throttle this thing so it doesn't flood the server with the? `getTicker` requests? thanks

Comment: First question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Regarding the second question: I would expect the browser to throttle the requests for you: it normally only allow N concurrent requests to a given host. You coud check that, and check why your server rejects these requests, because I'm not sure cending the requests one after the other would solve anything.

Comment: ok thanks. I actually just saw some documentation on Websockets APIs and particularly something called SocketCluster. My understanding is that it pretty much works the same way as the code above but the endpoint is actually meant for subscriptions (the current API I am using is  a REST API hence the errors when submitting a lot of requests, but the provider also exposes a websocket API, which I assume doesn't have this issue since it is a subscribe model). Anyway thanks and sorry if I sound new, I am used to code backend stuff in C.